# Merging model faces

Tags: modeling, optimization

Can anybody give me a hint whether it is possible to merge neighbouring faces of the model which edges are not straight? 
I've made in photoscan 3d model of a few sculptures. Program is good but I wanted to add a base for it and refine it a bit in Blender.

Edges of the surface look more like a saw than a straight line, thereforeI'd like to ask whether ther is a possibility of merging faces extruded from such edges into one face (or at least smaller number of faces). If yes - how to do that?

This is how the edges are aligned:
[image]

I was going to clean it up and download on Sketchfab to give others chance to see it. This is purely for display - not for 3d print.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: As always, it depends entirely on the purpose of your model (still render, animation, 3D game asset, printing). So without knowing more, my answer would be "Well, yes - maybe, but no."

Comment: Pycoder - You can find the screenshot in the edited question.
Methapor - I am aware that it is not simple :) Thanks for pointing this down. To be more specific: model is going to be uploaded on Sketchfab. I do not have any plans to print it or use in a game. I am looking for a possibility to simplify and refine a model for more smooth display via web browsers

Comment: I would advise against merging selected faces on the screenshot as that would create an awful Ngon in the bottom of the mesh which might provide you with just unexpected surprises like unsupported Ngons for any other application or strange shading artifacts. There aren't that many faces at least compared with the print itself.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to select all the edges of the faces in question. The image below illustrates how to select edge loops

[image: Select appropriate edge loops]

Then, scale those edges down to 0 along the appropriate World axis. In this case, S - Y - 0.

[image: Scale edges]

Finally, select all the faces between those edges, go to the Tool Shelf (T) and select Delete--> Limited Dissolve

[image: Limited Dissolve]

The result will be one face

[image: Result]

I hope the above makes sense ;)

Comment: Thanks Thistle. It works. It did not merge all faces into one - geometry of the edges is way to complex I suppose - but significantly reduced its amount. And finally they're aligned properly! :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad you've worked it out.